# What are the things need to taken care while working with flash playeres?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash

I have been working since a long time on a particular flash(Action Script 3.0) project and did all the test and development under the Flash itself(tested by **Ctrl+Enter**) . But It should be compatible with the browser, so i exported all these to my localhost, and its working fine.

But unexpectedly I got many more errors from swf player. I don't know why flash player on the browser behaves like this. All functions are working fine in Flash but when I export to swf its not working correctly...

Comment: What are the errors? Post error statements - we can't guess your errors

Comment: @Amarghosh there is no error showing, but unexpected outputs are getting.. I have a container which contains some moveclips and if i wish to click and drag, it works fine in flash, but on browser there are so much delay. and other similar events.... if the pacement of the drag object also miss behaves in browser. Its all working very very correct in flash, not in browsers :(

Answer (score 0):

The browser in the authoring environment is much more lenient with it's sandbox, you're likely running into security issues.